# Count from 1 to 10 and repeat inside a button link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm looking for a way to write a script that counts from 1 to 10 and after 10 it will repeat, Inside a buttom link.

Example:

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='/page"1".html'">Submit</button>
```

First click goes to "url/page1.html"

Second click  to "url/page2.html"

Third to "url/page3.html"

Fourth to "url/page4.html"

And up to ten click "url/page10.html"

After the hit number 10, it must run repeat to 1 agin.

Example2:

First click goes to "url/page1.html", click 2 = "url/page2.html", click 3 = "url/page3.html", click 4 =  "url/page4.html, click 5 = "url/page5.html, click 5 = "url/page5.html, click 6 = "url/page6.html, click 7 = "url/page7.html, click 8 = "url/page8.html, click 9 = "url/page9.html click 10 = "url/page10.html and now repeat  click 11 = "url/page1.html, click 12 = "url/page2.html, click 13 = "url/page3.html, click 14 = "url/page4.html

Hope someone can give me a good example of how this should run, prefer php or javascript.

Comment: **a script that counts from 1 to 10 and after 10 it will repeat**, it will repeat what exactly ?

Comment: aften 10 to 1 agin.

Comment: you want to make it infinite loop?

Comment: I bit of a guess, but are you trying to figure out some type of pagination?

Comment: First click goes to "url/page1.html", click 2 = "url/page2.html", click 3 = "url/page3.html", click 4 =  "url/page4.html, click 5 = "url/page5.html, click 5 = "url/page5.html, click 6 = "url/page6.html, click 7 = "url/page7.html, click 8 = "url/page8.html, click 9 = "url/page9.html click 10 = "url/page10.html and now repeat  click 11 = "url/page1.html, click 12 = "url/page2.html, click 13 = "url/page3.html, click 14 = "url/page4.html hope you understand me.

Comment: After the first click the page will changed to another page, isn't it ? So do you have the same button in all pages ?

Comment: Just for clarity - are you trying to create **a single button** as a link, but that link changes each time you click it? e.g. the first time you click the button it links to `url/page1.html` 2nd time `url/page2.html` ... up to `url/page10.html`, after which it resets to `url/page1.html` ?

Answer (score 1):

How about this solution:

```
<button onclick="myScript(10)">Submit</button>

<script>

let currentPage = 1;

function myScript(totalPages) {
    if (currentPage === totalPages) {
        currentPage = 1;
        return window.location.href=`/page10.html`
    }
    currentPage = currentPage < totalPages ? currentPage + 1 : 1;
    return window.location.href=`/page${currentPage}.html`;
}

</script>
```

I did not test this, but I believe that even though there could be a mistake, the global reasoning would work for you. The fact that I put the total number of pages as parameter of the function allows you to use this again in other cases.

Can you tell me if it does ?

Comment: Except each time a new page loads (from `window.location.href`) the current page counter will be reset...

Comment: it works from 1 to 10 but after 10 it run 10 10 10 10 no repeate

Comment: Do you know that, After the first click the page will be changed to another page so all your script will be start from the beginning that's mean `currentPage`  will be equal to `1` for ever ?

Comment: Oh you're absolutely right, I can't believe I missed this! @M.jacobsem you just need to find a way to make `currentPage` a consistent variable (you can do that with `localStorage` for instance) :)

Comment: Let me check what I did wrong and come up with a better solution then :)

Comment: Edit: I forgot to reset the counter `currentpage` when its value weas equal to 10!

Comment: Please post the right version! i like your script. :)

Comment: Hallo its relly work fine but when it som to side 10 its dont reset ? please help

Comment: @M.jacobsem Are you using local storage? You just need to replace `let currentPage = 1` by `let currentPage = window.localStorage.getItem('currentPage') || 1;` and 'currentPage = 1` becomes `window.localStorage.setItem('currentPage', 1);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>

    <button onclick="window.location.href=getNextPage(document.URL)">Submit</button>

</body>
<script>
    function getNextPage(title){
        debugger;
        var currentPage = parseInt(title.slice(-6,-5));
        console.log(currentPage);
        var nextPage;
        if(currentPage==10){
            var nextPage = 0
        }
        else{
            var nextPage = ++currentPage;
        }
        return "page"+nextPage+".html";
    }
</script>
```

This method parses the URL of your current page and then uses it to increment the number that dictates what will be the next page. I breifly tested this, but let me know if there's anything I can help with.

NOTE: The current page slicing only works if your page URL is in the form page1.html and so on. If any changes should be made to that format, adjust this line accordingly.

Comment: You could use a RegExp to extract the page number from the URL, something like `/^.*page(\d{1,2})\.html$/` to avoid the problem with slicing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

***Example:***

```js
function goTonextPage() {
  if (!localStorage.lastPage) {
      localStorage.lastPage = 0;
  }
  var nextPage = Number(localStorage.lastPage) === 10 ? 1 : Number(localStorage.lastPage) + 1;
  localStorage.lastPage = nextPage;
  return window.location.href = '/page' + nextPage + '.html';
}
```

```html
<button onclick="goToNextPage();">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file **paginator.js**

Add:

```
function navigateToNext() {
     var regex = /page([\d]+).html/;
     var matches = regex.exec(location.pathname);
     if (matches[1]) {
         localtion.href = "/page"+((matches[1]+1)%10+1)+".html";
     }
}
```

Your button should be:

```
<button onclick="navigateToNext()">Submit</button>
```

Don't forget to include the script in all pages it's needed:

```
<script src='paginator.js'></script>
```